# How can I remove last character in input value after regex validation? (Angular8)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Hello Im trying to remove last digit of the string and change the value of the input every time my function checks if on keypress input value is true on regex test. it work on first try but then it adds another then it works and then it adds another digit.  https://jsfiddle.net/kriala/qk0Lu4g2/1/

```
      <div>
        <label>Recipients:</label>
        <input (keydown)="phoneNumberLength()"  type="tel" class="form-control emailinput" [value]="keyValue" placeholder="Enter Phone Numbers" formControlName="user_phone">
        <div *ngIf="user_phone.errors">error</div>
      </div>
```

```
export class MailCreatorComponent implements OnInit{
public Editor = ClassicEditor;
public keyValue = '';
isMailCreator: boolean ;
filterFromGroup: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
user_phone: ['', [Validators.minLength(9), Validators.maxLength(9), Validators.pattern('[0-9]+')]],
subject: ['', [Validators.required]],
mailText: [''],
allUsers: ['', [Validators.required]],
});
get user_phone(){
return this.filterFromGroup.get('user_phone');
}
get subject() {
return this.filterFromGroup.get('subject');
}
clicked() {
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.filterFromGroup.value));
}
phoneNumberLength () {
  let regexpNumber = new RegExp('^[+0-9]{0,9}$');
  this.keyValue = this.user_phone.value;
  if (!regexpNumber.test( this.keyValue)) {
  this.keyValue =  this.keyValue.slice(0,  this.keyValue.length - 1);
 console.log(this.keyValue);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to only allow 9 digits at your phone input? And when the 10th digit is pressed, erase it?

Comment: isn't it easier to specidy maxlength=9?
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some changes, Hope this is what you are looking for [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxbbws)

Comment: it worked thank you. Can you explain a bit if its no problem what was the solution?

Comment: @PranavRamachandran - You should decribe **in the answer** what you did and why it solves the problem.